# \sectionmark not working on the first page with book documentclass and titlesec

Tags: header-footer, books

I would like to kindly ask for a help.

I am using two sided book documentclass, and I have a long section title.
My main question is how to make it shorter in the headers. It seems to interfeer with titlesec package (which I am using for something else).

I tried the following from the https://texfaq.org/FAQ-runheadtoobig

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{1ex plus 0ex minus .2ex}{3ex}


\begin{document}
    \chapter{test}
    \paragraph{Test paragraph}
    \lipsum

    \section[This is a loooooooong looooooooooong looooooooooooong title in TOC]{This is a loooooooong looooooooooong looooooooooooong title%
        \sectionmark{This is a loooooooong looooooooo\ldots}}
    \sectionmark{This is a loooooooong looooooooo\ldots}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

but it is not working, I still get the header on the first page of section long.
I would be happy even for some automated variant.

Thank you
Libor

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please -- as usual here -- make your given code snippet be compilable, the we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Welcome!  Without a complete example, it's impossible to say why `\sectionmark` isn't working.  But there's an alternative:   `\markright{Short title}`.  (I'm sure this has already been covered, but I can't find a suitable reference quickly.)

Comment: I am really, sorry I found out that it is due to the titlesec package I am using for something else. sorry for blaming \sectionmark however the \markright{Short title} does not fix it.

Comment: Thank you, I have added a minimum working example.

Comment: Indeed, `titlesec` changes the handling of the default marks.  If you always want the full section title in the TOC, you can use the optional short title just for the header by applying the option `[toctitles]` to the `\usepackage{titlesec}` line.

Answer (score 1):

In the `book`, and other standard classes the divisional commands, like `\chapter` take one optional argument.

```
\chapter[title for Toc and header]{Main title}
```

It seems that you want a short title in the header but long ones in the ToC and body.

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`) offers two optional arguments like:

```
\chapter[toc-title][head-title]{main-title}
\chapter[toc-and-head-title]{main-title}
\chapter{main-title} % main title used in all three places
```

And similarly for `\section` and the other divisional commands.

Perhaps consider using the `memoir` class.

Comment: Thank you very much. I do not have an issue with \chapter that one works fine. It appears for \section. I am a bit scared what else will be broken with memoir but thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Just put additional `\sectionmark` before `\section`

```
\sectionmark{This is a loooooooong looooooooo\ldots}
\section[This is a loooooooong looooooooooong looooooooooooong title in TOC]{This is a loooooooong looooooooooong looooooooooooong title}
\sectionmark{This is a loooooooong looooooooo\ldots}
```

Comment: This is not a useful answer, because, although it puts up the short section title, it puts it up with the number of the preceding section.